# Laravel 5 cache folder name causing classloader.php 412 error

Tags: laravel-5

When I uploaded my laravel 5 application to hostgator, i changed the name of one of the folders (instructor) that contains some controllers to (Instructors). However, I'm getting the error **ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412**

the applications is looking for controllers under the old folder name (instructor).

How can i fix this issue please?

Thank you

Comment: Never mind. just had to run composer dumpautoload.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following command:
composer dumpautoload

Answer (score 0):

perhaps u don't have controller.php file in the controllers folder under http folder of ur project.
Look for this file first..because in this file controller itself gets extended from basecontroller class, therefore it is necessary that this file should be there.